# OPENROWSET From EXCEL Not Executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am currently experiencing some issues with using OPENROWSET to read xlsx files.

```
SELECT *
INTO #TempRawData
FROM OPENROWSET
(
'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0',
--'Excel 12.0; Database={LOOP(CurrentValueXArray|0)}; HDR=NO; IMEX=1',
'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\root\DATA\Filename.xlsx; HDR=NO; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [Housekeeping$]'
)
```

Essentially it will just never run the logic, it just continues to execute the query indefinitely. It isn't a large file or a large amount of data, so it usually will take less than a second to run. When trying to cancel the query, it takes a VERY long time.

We had this issue 2 or 3 weeks ago on another server, so we decided to run the query logic locally where the files are stored, but now as of this morning we are experiencing the same issue. I have attempted to restart the machine, restart the SQL Server service, different files and locations. Nothing appears to work.

When looking at sp_who2, it just shows with a RUNNABLE status and an EXECUTE command.

Any ideas here?

Comment: After restarting the service, I get this error when the script is first run. Every time after that is where it is indefinitely running:
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.

Comment: The ACE provider is not officially supported for SQL Server because of these kinds of problems. It's not designed to be used as part of a service process. Consider switching to some other kind of import process, such as SSIS or Bulk Copy.

Comment: Not that simple. There are thousands of files all dynamically named based on location, department, date, etc. We use a program called VisualCron to handle this.